# scrollViewDidScroll not called in a CollectionView with custom layout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I want to load more data when the user reaches the end of my CollectionView. Unfortunately, scrollViewDidScroll is never called.

For my CollectionView, I use a custom layout and I think the problem could be at this:

```
    if let layout = exploreCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? CustomLayout {
        layout.delegate = self
    }
```

My class:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate { .....
```

I want to check if the function scrollViewDidScroll works:

```
    // Check if a user wants to load more data at the bottom
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("scrolled")
}
```

How do I implement the scrollViewDidScroll in my CustomLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollViewDidScroll` is a `UIScrollViewDelegate` method. So you need to make self (`MyViewController`) a delegate of the collectionview:

`exploreCollectionView.delegate = self`

And then for instance in an extension:

```
extension MyViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      print("scrolled")
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Koen. I thought there would be a problem with if let layout = exploreCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? CustomLayout {
        layout.delegate = self
    }